# Cannot ping some IPs (others work)

Tags: ping

With my ubuntu 18.04 some IPs I cannot ping, others I can

E. g.

```
ping 129.206.100.169
```

is not successful,

but

```
ping 128.65.210.8
```

works.
Before everything worked fine, afaik there was not software update. (I now did one by
`sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` but this did not solve the problem.)
What could be the reason?

Comment: Please give us a broader picture of your issue. What is the initial issue you're facing (Why do you want to ping these ips) ?

Comment: @pLumo I cannot access several web sites e. g. for reading my mails. In Thunderbird I get time out for imap server for my university account but not for my private one. So I tracked it down to a ping problem.

Comment: might be you're behind a proxy/firewall?

Comment: @pLumo Maybe yes. (How can I see? Should I do a traceroute and post?) But until yesterday everthing was fine. And from a Windows PC being in the same WiFi everthingy works also now.

Comment: @pLumo Now the problem does not exist any more. I did nothing. Maybe it was the firewall. I had the same prob once again, so the reason would be interesting. But without reproducing it at the moment this would be difficult. Thanks anyway!